# React error when using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using map in my react component to loop over a list. It works fine when I have one link inside the map loop however my second link returns an error when I try to create an optimized build for it. Intellij gives me an error saying after my `<a it expects either a ',' or a ')'`. I can't see that I've missed a bracket or anything.

```
{this.state.players.map(singlePlayer =>
       <Link to={'edit-player/' + singlePlayer.id}><li key={singlePlayer.id}>{singlePlayer.name}</li></Link>
       <a id={singlePlayer.id} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>delete</a>
                                    )}
```

Comment: ... And what error are you getting?

Comment: I think you may have posted the question before you were done, given how it ends mid-sentence. What is the exact error message? Where does this code appear? What is `Link`? (Presumably at some stage, `Link` wraps that `li` in a `ul` or `ol`?)

Comment: Yashika answered the question, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` should return only one element. So your code should be

```
{
  this.state.players.map((singlePlayer) => (
    <div>
      <Link to={"edit-player/" + singlePlayer.id}>
        <li key={singlePlayer.id}>{singlePlayer.name}</li>
      </Link>
      <a id={singlePlayer.id} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>
        delete
      </a>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, you are returning more than one item inside the `map`, you can't return more than one element, so you need to wrap the `Link` and `a` by either `div` or `li` or by any other element. try this:

```
{
  this.state.players.map((singlePlayer) => (
    <div>
      <Link to={"edit-player/" + singlePlayer.id}>
        <li key={singlePlayer.id}>{singlePlayer.name}</li>
      </Link>
      <a id={singlePlayer.id} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>
        delete
      </a>
    </div>
  ));
}
```